# Replacing & in invalid XML's

Tags: json, xml, ampersand

I have a requirement to convert an XML to JSON, parse the JSON and save it in the database as is (as it came in the incoming XML). The incoming XML's have data with both `&` and its HTML equivalent `&amp;`. To save such XML's, I tried replacing the `&` with their HTML equivalent, but that messes up things when I want to try to revert to the original data in the XML before saving them in the database. Any input on how this can be done will be appreciated.

Comment: What language or tool are you using to accomplish this?

Comment: I realise this isn't always an option, but one of the first things I do when someone or some system is sending me "invalid XML's" like this, is pointing them to the [XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) to let them know they aren't sending XML, as whatever they are sending does not conform to the XML spec.

Comment: I am using java for this.

Comment: If the source is really invalid XML, maybe you can convert all & to &amp; (thus &amp; will become &amp;amp;) making the conversion reversible? If you convert & and &amp; to the same value you can only revert them back to one of the two source values. Is the & actually invalid XML and not with one of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to establish whether the bug can be fixed at source: find out how the (non-)XML was generated, fix the program that created it, and then regenerate the data correctly.

If you have no alternative other than repairing the corrupt data, first investigate it so that you understand exactly what corruptions you are dealing with. In particular, establish all the patterns of data that use an ampersand both correctly and incorrectly.

Then use a text-based tool (not an XML-based tool) such as sed or perl to match the patterns you have discovered and correct them.

But treat this as a one-off and don't let it become normal. You wouldn't accept faulty goods from your suppliers, why should you accept faulty XML?